# dockerのvolume名変更方法は？

Tags: docker

docker volume lsで表示されるvolume nameの変更方法を教えてください。

Comment: [直接実現する方法は無さそう](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/33966#issuecomment-356980916)ですが、新しい名前で複製した後古い方を消す、という方法を採っている方が複数名いらっしゃるようです;[Rename docker volume · Issue #31154 · moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31154)。

Comment: ありがとうございました。リンクが参考になりました。そもそもはdocker runで動かしていたものをdocker-compose upに変えたら、違うボリューム名を付けられてしまったからでした。exportなどでデータを移行せず、名前を変えられたら、もとのデータを簡単に使えるようになるのでは？と思ったからでした。 以前のものを使うにはdocker-compose.ymlのvolumeを以下のようにexternalを使えば、できることがわかりました。 
`volumes: 
  jenkins_home:
    external: true`

Comment: @yukihane さん、もしよければ回答としてご投稿願えませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

(コメントより)

[直接実現する方法は無さそう](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/33966#issuecomment-356980916)ですが、新しい名前で複製した後古い方を消す、という方法を採っている方が複数名いらっしゃるようです;[Rename docker volume · Issue #31154 · moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31154)。   – @yukihane